# All unique combinations of n numbers

Tags: combinatorics

How is the algorithm or process called which calculates all unique combinations of n numbers? By unique I mean that this `1234` is the same as this `1243`.

Example:
Take this 4 numbers and list all unique combinations:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
12
13
14
23
24
34
123
124
134
234
1234
```

Comment: Why did you not take 134?

Comment: These are the non-empty subsets, and you can generate them all by running $k$ from $1$ to $2^{n}-1$, write $k$ as a binary $n$-digit number, and then generate the set for $k$ by adding $i$ if the $i$th binary digit of $k$ is $1$.

Comment: *Higher-Order Perl* discusses this problem and provides code to solve it, I think in Chapter 5. [It is available online for free](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/).

Comment: What if there are repetitions in the number? How would you find all unique combinations for 1134?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets of the set $\{1,...,n\}$. Given a number $k=1,...,2^n-1$, we can write the $k$ as an $n$-digit binary number, and then put $i$ in the set $A_k$ if the $i$th binary digit of $k$ is $1$.

For example, $n=3$ yields:
$$\begin{array}{cc}\text k & \text {binary} & \text{set}\\
1 & 001 & \{3\}\\
2 & 010 & \{2\}\\
3 & 011 & \{2,3\}\\
4 & 100 & \{1\}\\
5 & 101 & \{1,3\}\\
6 & 110 & \{1,2\}\\
7 & 111 & \{1,2,3\}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks! It's so simple why haven't I thought about to consider it as binary counting where each element represents a bit :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to list them, the easiest way is to count from $0$(if you allow the empty set) or $1$ (if not) to $2^n-1$ in binary.  At each value, use the bits that are turned on to represent the elements.  So when you get to $11_{10}=1011_2$ you output $134$

Answer (score 3):

For $n$ numbers, the output consists of $2^n-1$ entries, which is the number of nonempty subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Yeah, he wants to generate the list of them, it seems.

Comment: Thank you but that wasn't my question. I'd like to know the name of the process which calculates all uniqe combinations of n numbers. If there is a name :-)